# NPV Calculation on a PANDAS dataframe of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Am getting errors doing NPV calculation using numpy_financial.npv(rate, values) on a dataframe.

Am i able to use dataframes for NPV calculation?
Not sure how to fix this. Manually looping through each row?

```
npvValues =  ['value_1',' value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4', 'value_5', 'RFR']

round(df[npvValues].sample(5),1).sort_index(ascending=False)

DATE        value_1     value_2     value_3     value_4     value_5     RFR             
2017-04-03  38.5        92.8        168.7       257.0       354.0       2.1
2016-01-11  35.7        86.1        156.6       238.7       328.6       2.3
2013-07-29  28.1        67.8        123.3       187.8       258.6       2.3
2011-05-02  24.2        58.3        106.1       161.6       222.5       3.4
2010-01-18  24.4        58.8        107.0       163.0       224.5       3.8
```

NPV Calculation

```
value =  ['value_1',' value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4', 'value_5']

df['NPV_IV'] = npf.npv(rate=df['RFR']/100, values=df[value])
df['NPV_IV']
```

Here is the full error trace
[Full Error Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8G7a.png)

Comment: Can you post the error with a full trace?

Comment: Hey Luke, attached it to the post as a picture as there is too much text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

values parameter in npv takes only 1 dimensional array, so you need to loop through it.

```
df = pd.read_csv('t.csv')

value = ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4', 'value_5']

num = df[value].to_numpy()

rate_lists = df['RFR'].tolist()

new_col = []
for index, i in enumerate(num):
    n = npf.npv(rate=rate_lists[index] / 100, values=i)
    new_col.append(n)

df['NPV_IV'] = new_col
print(df)
         DATE  value_1  value_2  value_3  value_4  value_5  RFR      NPV_IV
0  2017-04-03     38.5     92.8    168.7    257.0    354.0  2.1  858.450837
1  2016-01-11     35.7     86.1    156.6    238.7    328.6  2.3  792.491237
2  2013-07-29     28.1     67.8    123.3    187.8    258.6  2.3  623.725804
3  2011-05-02     24.2     58.3    106.1    161.6    222.5  3.4  520.644433
4  2010-01-18     24.4     58.8    107.0    163.0    224.5  3.8  519.488982
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Still getting "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1154,) (5,) " with the mentioned solution.

Are you getting this at your end?

Comment: @JoshZ, it should work. May be you are jupyter notebook and the previous session still exists ? if it is, then may be restarting helps.

Comment: Ah..  maybe the issue was with the "df['RFR'] / 100" which i think we also need to convert to array?

Comment: @JoshZ, if you want rowise calculation, then yes it needs to convert to list and then use the correct index. please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Why is one .to_numpy() while the other is to_list()?

Comment: @JoshZ you should check the documentation, the rate param takes the scalar but the values param takes the 1d array: https://numpy.org/numpy-financial/latest/npv.html. Please mark at resolve if this has solved as your issues.